# rsync Synchronize only files with specific same name in all the subdirectories

Tags: rsync

I want to synchronize some files from a server to my local machine.
Particularly, for each directory and sub-directories contained in the synchronized main one, among all the present files, I would like to synchronize only the one which have a certain defined name (and only the updates of it, excluding the deleting of course).

Which command do i need to be able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To only copy any file called e.g. `myfile` from some source to some target:

```bsh
rsync -n -aim --include='myfile' --include='*/' --exclude='*' source/ target
```

This uses `--include` and `--exclude` to only consider your filename and any directories, but to ignore anything else. Since we're using `-m`, it would additionally not create directories that does not contain files called `myfile`.

The `-n` option stops anything from actually being copied, so you would test this until you are confident that it would work and then remove `-n` from the command. You should test this on a copy of you backed-up data.

Comment: It works and copy the file as I need, however if I change a file on the server, it does not change on the local as well.
Moreover, why you say we are using -m? I cannot see it.

Comment: @cmp666 If the file did not update, did you forget to remove `-n` from the command line? We're using `-m` to avoid creating/updating _directory entries_ on the destination that does not contain files with the name we're looking for. If you're syncing against an empty destination directory, you would otherwise end up with a lot of empty directories.

Comment: thank you very much. i removed -n otherwise it would not even copy the files from the cluster to local, but still when i modify on the cluster it doesnt update on the local. do i have to run the same command every time.. or maybe it just takes some time to update? i really appreciate your help!

Comment: i dont know how rsync checks if a file is being updated actually, maybe if you change like just a line it wont happen, it may need the size or the creation time to change. i thought it was able also to see the modification time of the file and transfer the update. is there a special flag to use for that in case is possible?

Comment: @cmp666 By default, `rsync` will update a file if its modification timestamp or size changes.  If you change a file in such a way that you don't modify any timestamp or the file's size, then it may skip that file. If this is the case, add the `-I` (`--ignore-times`) option to the `rsync` invocation.

Comment: i checked with stat filename and shows the different time for access,modify,change on the server, but not on local! :(

Comment: Maybe it depends on the server since it requires the password each time you want to copy something..?

Comment: @uhuhuhuhmdft Just check that you did not try with `-n`. If the `rsync` process fails to copy something due to permissions or authentication errors, there will be obvious error messages notifying you about this. I can't see what's happening on your server.

Comment: I did the command withou -n, otherwise it would have not copy anything at all. The secure copy goes fine, the problem is that it does not keep updating the files then.