# rsync do not update existing file after modification linux

Tags: rsync

I am using this command to copy and synchronize only the file with name 'myfile' between a server and a local pc.

```
 rsync -aim --include='myfile' --include='*/' --exclude='*' source/ target
```

unfortunately when i access and modify the file it does not update the changes.
I also checked the timestamps and the actions are actually recorded on the location where I did it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: -n = dry-run. remove it. See [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-n+-aim+--include%3D%27myfile%27+--include%3D%27*%2F%27+--exclude%3D%27*%27+source%2F+target)

Comment: sorry I forgot to remove -n in the question, that's was just a first trial, my problem is that I am exactly experiencing this without -n. Maybe it depends on the server since it requires the password each time you want to copy something..?

Comment: For reference, original question [rsync Synchronize only files with specific same name in all the subdirectories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/657640/100397)

Comment: Is the question, "_why do I have to enter a password each time I run this command_" or "_when I access and modify the file why does it does not update the changes_"?

Comment: You question text says, "_copy and synchronize [...] between a server and a local pc_" but your example command shows a copy between two parts of a single machine's filesystem. Which is it?

Comment: Maybe that's where is wrong. I do not want to make only a secure copy but to keep updating the files as well. I have to insert the passord the first time I copy and it makes sense, but I do not know if every time is updated a file this would be also required. In the latter case this tool would be not convenient.